# Need help on creating a mysql query

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have three tables - 1-FriendShip, 2-Users, 3-Pages.
Friendship table has fromUser, and toUser columns.
fromUser column contains the user who initiated friend request. toUser contains who received friend request (Inspired from Facebook)

I want to select data from Pages table who are friends with a given user, say 'user1'.
I can get the friends of user1 using this query:

```
  SELECT friends.`fromUser` AS `friend`
    FROM friends
    INNER JOIN users
    ON friends.`fromUser` = users.`userid`
    WHERE `friends`.`toUser`='user1'
 UNION
  SELECT friends.`toUser` AS `friend`
    FROM friends
    INNER JOIN users
    ON friends.`toUser` = users.`userid`
    WHERE friends.`fromUser`='user1'
```

This gives me result like this:

Friends
user2
user5

and so on...

I want to select the pages of all these users and order them in descending order by timestamp column. Anyone please provide a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IN`, assuming your Pages table has a `userid` (or equivalent) column:

```
SELECT * FROM Pages
WHERE userid IN (
   -- Your query to retrieve friends of user1
)
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for thinking differently and smartly. I forgot that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

So use the query you have as a derived table to join on:

```
SELECT *
FROM pages
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT friends.`fromUser` AS `friend`
    FROM friends
    INNER JOIN users
    ON friends.`fromUser` = users.`userid`
    WHERE `friends`.`toUser`='user1'
 UNION
  SELECT friends.`toUser` AS `friend`
    FROM friends
    INNER JOIN users
    ON friends.`toUser` = users.`userid`
    WHERE friends.`fromUser`='user1'
) AS friends ON pages.user = friends.friend
ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC
```